# Prove that $\sin(2^n \alpha)$ can be arbitrarily small

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

> Prove that $\sin(2^n \alpha)$ can be arbitrarily small where $\alpha = \tan^{-1}\left(\frac23\right)$ and $n$ is a positive integer.

I was wondering how I should go about solving this. Can we prove this by contradiction?

Comment: By what method do you want to prove this? Probabilistically your argument is true since $|sin(x)| $ is in the bounds $[0,1]$ and the values of your function are dense in the reals.

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen I just want to prove it mathematically. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: you can actually turn my comment above into a decent proof if you imagine stretching the values around the unit circle. Imagine your function as a point rotating around the unit circle. You now just need to prove that all points will be hit (with some additional justifications on top of that). Is there any reason for the $\alpha$ you chose?

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen Yes, as solving this would prove that the sequence defined by $x_1 = 3, x_{n+1} = \frac{x_n}{2}-\frac{2}{x_n}$ is unbounded.

Comment: As you said @BrevanEllefsen, I too think $\{ 2^n \alpha \mod 2\pi: n \in \mathbb{Z}^+\}$ is dense in $[0,2\pi]$ (but need to prove this more formally).

Comment: Have you already tried any of the techniques here?  http://math.stackexchange.com/q/4764/269764

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen It seems different here since we have $2^n$ instead of $k$.

Comment: @user19405892 OK, what about this link http://math.stackexchange.com/q/219135/269764

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen Could you show how to extend that to this question because that proves it for the interval $[-1,1]$ and without the constant like I have.

Comment: @user19405892 we want to prove it for the interval $[-1,1]$ because when we take the absolute value like we do in your post we get $[0,1]$. I agree the constant I a bit of an issue... I'll look into it a bit later unless someone more knowledgeable than me beats me to it!

Comment: @stud_iisc Do you know how to prove it?

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen The result may hold more generally and not just for $\alpha = \tan^{-1}(5/12)$.

Comment: @user19405892 I imagine it does. The ideas I have had aren't panning out though. I'm really hoping that someone who is way better at this can come and answer your question :/

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/680481/how-will-the-limit-lim-sinan-behave-for-a-1/682576#682576 can be helpful, but not settle your problem completely. From there, we know that your sequence does not converge to $0$, hence there are subsequences not converging to $0$.

Comment: @i707107 How did you determine that?

Comment: @user19405892 Sorry, my last comment about density in $[0,1]$ was not true, deleted it. It was for the lacunary sequences $(m_i)$ with $m_{i+1}/m_i \rightarrow 1$. The sequence $m_n = 2^n$ is lacunary, but $m_{n+1}/m_n =2$. So, the assumption of Lemma 2.23 in https://books.google.com/books?id=E04hAwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false is not satisfied.

Comment: The sequence not converging to $0$ can be proved via https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pisot%E2%80%93Vijayaraghavan_number and that $\frac1{\pi} \tan^{-1} (5/12)$ is irrational.

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen Was an answer to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/219135/how-many-limit-points-in-sin2n-how-many-can-there-be-in-a-general-seq deleted because I remember seeing one saying $\sin(2^n)$ was dense?

Comment: @user19405892 yes, I remember it. Appears to be missing

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen There was a step that the answer did not explain carefully. Maybe the one who wrote the answer is working on it. I think that whether $\sin(2^n)$ is dense or not is unknown, but the sequence is known to have at least two limit points. See this: http://www.kurims.kyoto-u.ac.jp/~kenkyubu/bessatsu/open/B34/pdf/B34-09.pdf

Comment: @i707107 I just recall that Jack has had his community project going recently that involves $\sin(2^n)$ which seems to confirm that the density is not known. See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1976417/269764) and [here](http://mathoverflow.net/a/252582/83537)

Comment: @i707107 it seems that this comes down to showing that $\pi$ is normal in base $2$, which confirms Yves' suspicions in their answer

Comment: Maybe $\beta=\frac{1}{\pi}\arctan\frac{2}{3}$ can be represented as $\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{a(n)}{2^n}$ for some suitable sequence $\{a(n)\}_{n\geq 1}$, ensuring that in the binary representation of $\beta$ there are strings of zeroes (or $1$s) with arbitrary length.

Comment: But that might not to hold just as well, disproving OP's claim.

Comment: @user19405892: I know, I just find it easier to think as travelling the binary representation of $\beta$. Is there some particular reason for expecting arbitrarily long runs of zeroes or ones? *Almost every number* has such a property, of course, but why $\beta$ is one of such numbers?

Comment: The reason I pick this $\beta$ is because this would prove that the sequence $x_1 = 3, x_{n+1} = \frac{x_n}{2}-\frac{2}{x_n}$ is unbounded

Comment: @user19405892: that simply follows by applying Newton's method to the correct convex function, and has nothing to do with complex numbers.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio You mean the fact that it is unbounded? If so, can you explain?

Comment: @user19405892: it is even simpler than that: assume that $\{x_n\}$ is bounded and derive a contradiction.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Please show a proof and this would solve the problem if you prove it is unbounded.

Comment: @user19405892 JackD'Aurizio seems right; but perhaps you can just post the actual problem as a new, well specified question (without the character limits of comments, and in fact not buried under 20+ other comments)?

Comment: Yet another related question: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/970480

Answer (score 11):

This isn't really a complete answer, but it is of interest since it converts the problem into a well known one. First, convert problem to $\cos (2^n \alpha)$ being made arbitrarily close to 1.

The Chebychev polynomials $T_m$ have the property that $\cos (m \alpha) = T_m(\cos \alpha)$. With $\alpha = \arctan(5/12)$ we have $\cos(\alpha) = 5/13$.

So we are interested in
$$a_n = T_{2^n}(5/12).$$

Now we have this wonderful identity for Chebychev polynomials that $T_m(T_n(x)) = T_{mn}(x)$. Using this, we obtain:

$$a_{n+1}= T_2(T_{2^n}(5/13)) = T_2(a_n).$$

Hence, this turns into studying the orbit of the iterated map $a_{n+1} = T_2(a_n)$ with $a_0 = 5/13$. In particular, $T_2(x) = 2x^2 -1$.

Take $y_n = -(x_n+1)/2$ so $x_n=-2y_n+1$ and
$$f(y)=(2y+1)^2-1=4y^2-4y=4y(1-y)$$
where $y_n=f(y_n)$ and $y_0=-9/13$.

This is the famous logistic map with parameter 4. Thus, $x_n$ being close to 1 (remember we switch is equivalent to $\cos$) $y_n$ being close to $1$. I'm pretty sure that for almost all initial points the orbits under the logistic map are dense. However, how this is proved may as just as well use facts about the original question.

Comment: The periodic points of the map $x_{n+1} = 4x_n(1-x_n)$ over $[0,1]$ are dense in $[0,1]$ from here: http://www.di.univr.it/documenti/OccorrenzaIns/matdid/matdid044153.pdf.

Comment: @user19405892 OK, so what does this tell us?

Comment: @user19405892 sorry, let me clarify - between abnry's post and your link, can we confirm the OP's conjecture, or do we need something tighter? Mappings and finite differences in general are not my forte.

Comment: @user19405892 The link shows that periodic points (the initial points $x_0$ that make $x_n$ periodic) are dense, not the points $x_n$'s. So, the question is still not confirmed.

Comment: No, it doesn't solve. See this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_map Logistic map with $r=4$ is just an equivalent formulation of your problem.

Comment: Are you sure that $\sin(m \alpha) = T_m(\sin(\alpha))$? That would mean that $\sin(2x) = 2\sin^2(x)-1$, which isn't always true.

Comment: @user19405892 You are correct, it should be $\cos(m\alpha) = T_m(\cos(\alpha))$.  But most of the argument goes through except we want to show $x_n$ comes arbitrarily close to $\pm1$, and $x_0 = 12/13$ (well, it would be if you didn't keep changing the initial value!).

Comment: Yes, thanks for pointing out that error. I realized it later but didn't correct. I will do so now.

Answer (score 6):

This is **not a complete answer**.

If we note $a_n=\sin{(2^n\alpha)}$ then
$$a_n=\sin{(2^n\alpha)}=2\sin{(2^{n-1}\alpha)}\cos{(2^{n-1}\alpha)}=2a_{n-1}\cos{(2^{n-1}\alpha)}$$
Initial value is irrational:
$$a_0=\sin{\alpha}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\frac{9}{4}}}=\frac{2}{\sqrt{13}}$$
however:
$$|a_1|=|\sin{2\alpha}|=2\frac{2}{\sqrt{13}}\frac{3}{\sqrt{13}}=\frac{12}{13}$$
$$|a_2|=|\sin{4\alpha}|=2\frac{12}{13}\frac{\sqrt{13^2-12^2}}{13}=\frac{120}{169}$$
$$|a_3|=|\sin{8\alpha}|=2\frac{120}{169}\frac{\sqrt{169^2-120^2}}{169}=\frac{28560}{28561}$$
$$|a_4|=|\sin{16\alpha}|=2\frac{28560}{28561}\frac{\sqrt{28561^2-28560^2}}{28561}=\frac{13651680}{815730721}$$
all **the subsequent values are rational**, because
$$|a_{n+1}|=2|a_n|\left|\sqrt{1-a_n^2}\right|=2|a_n|\sqrt{(1-|a_n|)(1+|a_n|)}=\\
2|a_n|\sqrt{\left(1-2|a_{n-1}||\cos{(2^{n-1}\alpha)}|\right)\left(1+2|a_{n-1}||\cos{(2^{n-1}\alpha)}|\right)}=\\
2|a_n|\sqrt{\left(a_{n-1}-\cos{(2^{n-1}\alpha)}\right)^2\left(a_{n-1}+\cos{(2^{n-1}\alpha)}\right)^2}=\\
2|a_n|\left|a_{n-1}-\cos{(2^{n-1}\alpha)}\right|\left|a_{n-1}+\cos{(2^{n-1}\alpha)}\right|=\\
2|a_n|\left|a_{n-1}^2-\cos^2{(2^{n-1}\alpha)}\right|=2|a_n|\left|2a_{n-1}^2-1\right|$$
and by induction $a_n \in \mathbb{Q}, \forall n>0$. It's impossible not to mention the striking appearance of [Pythagorean Triples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple) due to this fact, e.g. for $|a_2|$ - $(5, 12, 13)$ and for $|a_3|$ - $(119, 120, 169)$:
$$|a_n|=\frac{2mn}{m^2+n^2}$$
then
$$|a_{n+1}|=2|a_n|\left|\sqrt{1-a_n^2}\right|=2\frac{2mn}{(m^2+n^2)^2}|m^2-n^2|=...$$
where by noting $m_1=2mn$, $n_1=|m^2-n^2|$ we have $m_1^2+n_1^2=(m^2+n^2)^2$
$$...=\frac{2m_1n_1}{m_1^2+n_1^2}$$
These fractions don't seem to be reducible and repeating (again, by induction and using $\gcd(m,n)=1$, $m$-even, $n$-odd), for example
$$|a_{n+2}|=\frac{2m_2n_2}{m_2^2+n_2^2}=\frac{4m_1n_1|m_1^2-n_1^2|}{(m_1^2+n_1^2)^2}=\frac{8mn|m^2-n^2||(2mn)^2-(m^2-n^2)^2|}{(m^2+n^2)^4}$$
thus, **there is no periodicity**.

I should also mention [this result from the wikipedia article about logistic maps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_map#Solution_in_some_cases), saying that

> $$a_n^2=\sin^2{(2^n\pi \theta)}$$ for rational $\theta$, after a
>   finite number of iterations $a_{n}^2$ maps into a periodic sequence.

by contradiction, $\theta=\frac{\alpha}{\pi}$ is not rational.

This may not answer the original question, but, at least, reveals some structure.

Comment: Nice observation. It looks like that you proved $\alpha/\pi$ is irrational. This can be proved via simpler way using algebraic integers.

Comment: @i707107 yes, I agree. Proving irrationality of $\frac{\alpha}{\pi}$ came as a side effect of studying the structure of the sequence.

Answer (score 4):

**This is not an answer - just a brief argument of why obtaining the proof, or the proof of the converse, appears extremely difficult and likely to elude casual attempts**.

Note that $|\sin(2^n a)|$ can be made arbitrarily small if and only if $2^n a$ can be made arbitrarily close to an integer multiple of $\pi$; i.e. if and only if the fractional part of $\frac{2^n a}{\pi}$ can be made arbitrarily close to $0$ or to $1$; i.e. if and only if the binary representation of $\frac{a}{\pi}$ contains arbitrarily long sequences of $0$s, or arbitrarily long sequences of $1$s.

It is currently unknown if the binary representation of $\pi$ or $\pi^{-1}$ contains arbitrarily long sequences of $0$s or of $1$s (however, note that this is a weaker property than normality in base $2$, implied by, but not equivalent to it). Thus proving or disproving that the binary representation of $\frac{a}{\pi}$ contains arbitrarily long sequences of $0$s or of $1$s appears beyond the reach of current mathematics, unless one can prove that $a$ has some “special property” that “cancels out the $\pi-$ness” from $\frac{a}{\pi}$ (which *seems* unlikely for $a=\tan^{-1}(\frac{2}{3})$).

Answer (score 2):

The above claim means:

$\hspace{1cm}$ For each $\, \delta>0\, $ exists $\, n\in\mathbb{N}\, $ and $\, m\in\mathbb{N}_0\, $ such that $\enspace\displaystyle |m-2^n \frac{\arctan\frac{2}{3}}{\pi} |<\delta$ .

The problem now is to find out if for $\frac{\arctan\frac{2}{3}}{\pi}=:0.a_1 a_2 a_3 ...$ with all $a_j\in\{0;1\}$

the length of all binary squences $a_{n+k+1}...a_{n+k+l}=0$ are limited or if there can be

always found a longer sequence than any previous one (with which we can proof the claim).

There is no regularity in the sequence for $\frac{\arctan\frac{2}{3}}{\pi}$ and therefore it seems to be that

the claim cannot be proofed (or disproofed).

Answer (score 2):

**Thoughts on using $\tan$ formulas... not an answer, yet.**

Note that if $\sin(\theta)$ is very close to zero, $\tan(\theta)$ is also very close to zero and and $|\tan(\theta)| \approx |\sin(\theta)|$ to increasing accuracy closer to zero; but in particular $|\tan(\theta)| > |\sin(\theta)|$, so if we can show that $\tan(2^n\alpha)$ gets arbitrarily close to zero, that guarantees the same for $\sin(2^n\alpha)$.

So we can use the double angle formula for $\tan$ :

$$\tan(2\theta) = \frac{2\tan\theta}{1-\tan^2\theta}
$$

to determine $\tan(2^n\alpha)$ for successive values of  $n$, without converting to either $\sin$ values or angles.

Converting this into recurrence formulas for a rational number with integer  numerator $N(n)$  and denominator $D(n)$, we have:

$N(0)=2, D(0)=3$
$N(n+1)=2N(n)\cdot D(n)$
$D(n+1)=D(n)^2-N(n)^2$

Unfortunately these get too large too quickly to be of particular value.

---

I'm still thinking about how to carry this forward.....

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer, but it greatly simplifies the problem.

$sin(2^n\alpha)$ can get arbitrarily small if and only if $2^n\alpha$ can get arbitrarily close to $0$ or $\pi$ (mod $\pi$).

It can be proven that $2^n\alpha \equiv \pi \cdot (0.b_nb_{n+1}...)_{2} $ (mod $\pi$)
, where $0.b_0b_1 ...$ is the binary representation of the fractional part of $\frac{\alpha}{\pi}$. The proof is done by induction:

$(0.b_0b_1 ...)_2$ = {$\frac{\alpha}{\pi}$} $\iff \alpha \equiv \pi \cdot (0.b_0b_1 ...)_2$ (mod $\pi$) as the starting case.

$2^n\alpha \equiv \pi \cdot (0.b_nb_{n+1}...)_{2} $ (mod $\pi$) $\iff (0.b_nb_{n+1} ...)_2$ = {$\frac{2^n\alpha}{\pi}$} $\iff (0.b_{n+1}b_{n+2} ...)_2$

= {$2${$\frac{2^n\alpha}{\pi}$}} = {$\frac{2^{n+1}\alpha}{\pi}$} $\iff 2^{n+1}\alpha \equiv \pi \cdot (0.b_{n+1}b_{n+2} ...)_2$ (mod $\pi$) as the induction.

So the conjecture is true if and only if you can find arbitrarily long sequences of $1$'s or $0$'s in the binary representation of $\frac{\alpha}{\pi}$.